# Trying to make a custom string class and I keep getting C2440 and a E0415 errors

Tags: c++

I'm self teaching from a book.  I'm using this example from a book to work with a custom string class and and I keep getting

Error (active)  E0415   no suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char [15]" to "Stringz"
and
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [15]' to 'Stringz'

please help me understand what's wrong.
I've got a pointer to char in the private field.  the constructor initializes with whatever was sent from main as an argument, the length of the argument is taken and used to dynamically allocate the appropriate amount of memory, and finally the address is put in *str in the private field.  I tried putting.  Any input is appreciated

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Stringz
{
private:
    char* str;
public:

    Stringz(char* s)
    {
        int length = strlen(s);
        str = new char[length + 1];
        strcpy(str, s);
    }
    ~Stringz()
    {
        cout << "deleting.." << endl;
        delete[]str;
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    
    Stringz s1 = "made a string ";

    s1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, the `char*` and `const char*` types are distinct. Your string literal is a `const` array of `char` so it can 'decay' into a `const char*` but *not* to a `char*` (otherwise, a function may try to modify it's contents, which is not allowed).

To get your `Stringz` from that literal, you need to make the constructor take a `const char*` argument:

```cpp
    Stringz(const char* s)
    {
        int length = strlen(s);
        str = new char[length + 1];
        strcpy(str, s);
    }
```

You can still use this constructor to make a `Stringz` from a *non*-const `char` array, because the complier can *safely* cast a non-const into a const. (This is, of course, assuming that the constructor doesn't do anything to try to modify the argument it is given - and yours doesn't.)

Comment: Ok, that did the trick.  I really appreciate your clarification!

Answer (score 1):

- you would certainly need to store the length of your string as a private field (or you'd need to calculate it every time again)
- you're accepting `char*` in the constructor, but string literal has a type `const char *` which is not suitable where `char*` is expected

**! Wrong part of the initial answer !**

`= "made a string "` is calling an assignment operator (so called `operator=`) which you didn't write. To call a constructor you use `Stringz s1("made a string ")` or `String s1{"made a string "}`, but there are more problems in your code than that:

Comment: Technically, it's not an *assignment* but an *initialization*, and the constructor is called.

Comment: @AdrianMole now that I tried to compile it myself, I agree. Shame on me

Comment: Even if you actually define an assignment operator like `Stringz& operator = (const char* src)`, then the ***constructor*** will still be called in that case!